# Comparate different lines of a column

Tags: c++, multiple-columns, string-comparison

I have a file `.dat` with two columns, like this but with more lines:

```
TEMP.       PRESSURE   
-9.833374   0.156921        
-9.831743   0.157021    
-9.838824   0.157101   
-9.839035   0.157226
```

For each columns, I want to comparate the value of the *n-line* (for instance of the first column), with the one of the (`n+1`)lines (of the same column) and this comparison will be the condition that I'll put in a if structure.

Solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've made a program that extracts only the columns that i need from a .dat file and i save them in another file. Now i have to calculate the mean and standard deviations of these values but with the respect of a condition: the difference between the value of the n-line and the value of the (n-1) line should be less than a constant value chosen by me. I don't know how to make this condition.

Answer (score 2):

Read the whole file to a two dimension matrix and then just compare the columns.
Like this, for example:

`double matrix[2][2] = { {-9.833374, 0.156921},  {-9.831743, 0.157021} };`

Then you can just compare them like this:

`matrix[line x][column] == matrix[line y][column]`

Comment: Looks like the expression will always be true because the `nth-line` row is always equal to the `nth-line` row.

Comment: By nth-line line I mean any line number. It could be 5 and 3 or whatever. I will edit it to remove the ambiguity